# Xcode 8.3 command line C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a simple program in Xcode 8.3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverseString(int);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    reverseString(123456);
    return 0;
}

void reverseString(int numString){
    
    if(numString < 10){
        cout<<numString;
    }else{
        cout<<numString % 10;
        reverseString(numString/10);
    }
}
```

The code just prints out a number in its reverse order.

When I run the program in Xcode I get

> Program ended with exit code: 0

Rewrite the program with a print statement in the main function like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

cout<<"Hello";
reverseString(123456);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the same output

> Program ended with exit code: 0

If I add \n to the send of the print statement `cout<<"Hello\n";`

I get:

> Hello
>
> Program ended with exit code: 0

What is going on here? I recently updated to Xcode 8.3, could that be causing the issue? If so, how can I fix this?

Note: I am creating my project by selecting file -> new project -> MacOS -> Command Line Program

Also note: Programs I've created in the past still run properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cout won't print anything untill you send a "\n", so at some point in your code you need to do cout << "\n";

Comment: Is there a reason why that is? Thats specific to Xcode correct? Other IDEs will print the statement correctly without the cout<<"\n"

Comment: I don't believe it it specific to Xcode. The purpose is to allow you to build up a string for output to the standard output terminal from multiple lines of code, with the line only being emitted once it is terminated with \n (or std::endl )

Comment: You could always call cout.flush() to force the output, out.

Comment: But other IDEs print the statement correctly, and so does terminal on Mac. Do they just input it themselves somehow?

Comment: It is interesting that it works on other IDEs (compilers, whatever) but it remains true that to guarantee the output you either need to use the end-of-line terminator, or flush the output.